# Initializing smart pointers in a tuple without knowing the type

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, stdtuple, stdapply

I have a tuple of smart pointers (as a member of a class template) that I need to initialize. I use std::apply to iterate over tuples elsewhere, but how do I initialize them with new objects without knowing their type? Running the code below with a debugger tells me the elements in the tuple are still "empty" afterwards. What am I doing wrong here?

```
struct A {
  int a = 1;
}

struct B {
  int b = 2;
}

std::tuple< std::unique_ptr< A >, std::unique_ptr< B > > my_tuple;

std::apply( [] ( auto&... ptr ) { //std::unique_ptr< T >
  (..., ptr.reset( { } )); //ptr.reset( new T() )
}, my_tuple );
```

Comment: You can use `decltype` to find out the type of `ptr` and then use `element_type` to know what kind of object it points to.

Comment: And regarding `{}`, it gets converted to `nullptr` in this case, since `reset` takes a pointer.

Comment: What do you need to initialize the `tuple` with? Pointers to created instances? Is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/WEKqfbqqK) something close to what you want?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux What's wrong with using `std::apply` here?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Once you have a pack, you can fold it, as OP did. I've posted an answer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh I see. I haven't had a chance to get familiar with fold expressions yet.

Comment: @TedLyngmo For simplicity's sake, I wasn't trying to pass anything, but it would be nice to pass something along that would be type dependent. Maybe something from a matching tuple. Anyway, it didn't occur to me to replace the whole tuple. It's certainly simpler :)

Comment: @AreN I'm still not sure I get it so I put up an answer with a few options.

Comment: Btw, if the `unique_ptr`s in the tuple are always supposed to point at objects, do they really need to be pointers? Why not simply `tuple<A,B>`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo You already had a good alternative there, where you could pass the existing tuple. I was just considering that one might have some specific parameter to initialize with, and that another template parameter pack could be used for that, but I think it's outside the scope of the original problem. And certainly, not using pointers at all is an option, but then there wouldn't be a problem! :)

Comment: @AreN Yeah, I wasn't sure what you needed so I included a more versatile variant in my answer. With the second overload in the answer, creating a `tuple` with `unique_ptr`s to copies of objects in a parameter pack can be done if you need that. ... and I agree to some degree, what's the fun in avoiding these problems? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you can apply `decltype` to `ptr` to get the type of the `unique_ptr`, then apply `element_type` to it:

```
std::apply([](auto &... ptr)
{
    ((ptr = std::make_unique<typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(ptr)>::element_type>()), ...);
}, my_tuple );
```

<sup>(I've replaced `new` with `make_unique`, and moved `...` to the end, but those are just style clanges.)</sup>

This can be shortened with C++20 template lambdas:

```
std::apply([]<typename ...P>(std::unique_ptr<P> &...ptrs )
{
    ((ptrs = std::make_unique<P>()), ...);
}, my_tuple );
```

Comment: Several good alternatives have been presented, but this one just made the problematic code work.
As previously commented, `unique_ptr.reset` expects a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of what use-cases you want to support so I made a few function templates that may suit what you are trying to do.

```
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

// create a tuple of unique_ptr's pointing to default constructed objects
template<class... Ts>
std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Ts>...> init_up_tuple() {
    return std::make_tuple(std::make_unique<Ts>()...);
}

// create a tuple of unique_ptr's with copies of the supplied objects
template<class... Ts>
std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Ts>...> init_up_tuple(const Ts&... ts) {
    return std::make_tuple(std::make_unique<Ts>(ts)...);
}

// create a tuple of unique_ptr's with default constructed objects of the same
// types as those in the supplied tuple
template<class... Ts>
std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Ts>...> init_up_tuple(
    const std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Ts>...>&)
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::make_unique<Ts>()...);
}

namespace detail {
template<class... Ts, size_t... Idx>
std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Ts>...> copy_up_tuple_impl(
    const std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Ts>...>& tu,
    std::index_sequence<Idx...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(std::make_unique<Ts>(*std::get<Idx>(tu))...);
}
} // namespace detail

// create a tuple of unique_ptr's pointing to copy constructed objects
// from the objects in the supplied tuple of unique_ptr's
template<class... Ts, typename Indices = std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>>
std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Ts>...> copy_up_tuple(
    const std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<Ts>...>& tu)
{
    return detail::copy_up_tuple_impl(tu, Indices{});
}
```

These could then be used like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int a = 1;
};

struct B {
    int b = 2;
};

int main() {
    auto t1 = init_up_tuple<A, B>();  // default constructed
    std::cout << std::get<0>(t1)->a << ' ' << std::get<1>(t1)->b << '\n';

    A a{3};
    auto t2 = init_up_tuple(a, B{4}); // copy construct from the supplied objects
    std::cout << std::get<0>(t2)->a << ' ' << std::get<1>(t2)->b << '\n';

    auto t3 = copy_up_tuple(t2);      // copy construct from tuple of unique_ptr's
    std::cout << std::get<0>(t3)->a << ' ' << std::get<1>(t3)->b << '\n';

    t3 = init_up_tuple(t3);           // reset to default
    std::cout << std::get<0>(t3)->a << ' ' << std::get<1>(t3)->b << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1 2
3 4
3 4
1 2
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xMz5r7n4x)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reset the unique pointers to the default for the types, you can iterate over the values in a tuple using numerical index like below

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int u;
    A() : u(5) {};
};

struct B {
    int v;
    B() : v(6) {};
};

template<size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
void reset_tuple_of_unique_ptrs(std::tuple<Tp...>& t) {

    auto& item = std::get<I>(t);
    using T = typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(item)>::element_type;

    item.reset( new T() );
    if constexpr (I + 1 != sizeof...(Tp))
        reset_tuple_of_unique_ptrs<I + 1>(t);
}

int main() {
    std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<A>, std::unique_ptr<B>> tup = { std::make_unique<A>(), std::make_unique<B>() };
    std::get<0>(tup)->u = 42;
    std::get<1>(tup)->v = 17;

    std::cout << std::get<0>(tup)->u << " , " << std::get<1>(tup)->v << "\n";
    
    reset_tuple_of_unique_ptrs(tup);

    std::cout << std::get<0>(tup)->u << " , " << std::get<1>(tup)->v << "\n";
}
```